# Change text color of a specific column for QTreeView

Tags: qt, stylesheet, selecteditem, qtreewidget

I have widget that inherits from QTreeView, and I want to change the text color, but only for a specific column. Currently I set the stylesheet, so the entire row changes the text color to red when the item is selected.

```
QTreeView::item:selected {color: red}
```

I want to change only the color of the first column when the item is selected. I know how to change the colour for specific columns (using ForegroundRole on the model and checking the index column), but I don't know how to do check if the index is selected in the model.

Comment: QTreeWidget or QTreeView?

Comment: Sorry, QTreeView... I will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a delegate for that:

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
        if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
            QStyleOptionViewItem optCopy = option;
            optCopy.palette.setColor(QPalette::Foreground, Qt::red);
        }
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, optCopy, index);
    }
}

myTreeWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new MyDelegate);
```

Comment: that works, thanks! I tried a slightly different approach, I will post it in case anyone prefers the other.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I solved it.

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const { 
        QString text_highlight;
        if (index.column() == 0)){
            text_highlight = BLUE;
        } else{
            text_highlight = RED;
        }
        QStyleOptionViewItem s = *qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItem*>(&option);
        s.palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, QColor(text_highlight));
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, s, index);
    }
}
```